"addr:street" seems to be missing after using osm2pgsql to load data into postGIS
I have some geographic usecases for a personal usage (i.e. real-estate price forecast), and after digging through different tools, I wanted to learn more about PostGIS.
osm2pgsql seemed like a great tool for what I wanted to do, but after ingesting my osm data (which I downloaded from Geofabrik), it clearly appeared that the majority of the columns / keys where missing.
After some digging, I found out that there was a default.style file which I updated to add "addr:street" or "addr:postcode".
Even though the columns have been added to the table, if I pick a random city, I clearly don't have all the result I would be expecting for.
For example :
SELECT DISTINCT "addr:street"
FROM planet_osm_polygon
WHERE "addr:postcode" = '75001'

will return just ~25 results, which is not all the streets present in the first arrondissement of Paris.
Have you any advises what I might do wrongly, and what preferred tools I might investigate if osm2pgsql is not the best one for my usecases?
Here is the osm2pgsql command I am running for ingesting my data:
osm2pgsql -S geoanalysis.style -c ile-de-france.osm.pbf


Information is not repeated (but can be in some cases), so the postal code is not part of the address. Even the street name could be dissociated from the civic number point. You can try to first select the postal code polygon, then get the streets inside.

I checked some random addresses from Paris, for example https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/806898363. It seems that a) housenumbers are attached on points, b) address points do not usually have addr:street, c) address points do not usually have addr:postcode. Maybe you should try to find some pre-processed dataset. Perhaps this page helps https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/FR:France/Base_Adresses_Nationale_Ouverte_(BANO).

This approach will fail since in OSM address data is stored in a hierarchical way. This means you have to look at multiple elements to determine the full address. Instead, use a geocoder which already pre-processed and merged all these information for easy querying. Take a look at Nominatim for example.

Thank-you very much for your answers all. After digging through, it indeed appears that the data is stored in a hierarchical way, and finding information might be harder than I thought. I'll take a look at Nomatim, thanks @scai for the heads-up.

Just to close up the topic, and maybe helping other people struggling like me in the future :
(Disclosure, what I say might not be accurate, being currently learning the tools)

The data is being stored in a hierarchical way, meaning that to look for a particular address, you have to dig through different layer of the data

A very helpful osm2pgsql argument, that helped me with understanding my data, was the --hstore-all -j, which adds all tags to a hstore column


By playing around with the data, I was able to find the buildings associated with a particular street. For example, the street Rue de Seine, with osm_id=4227146 :
-- Find all the buildings in 'Rue De Seine' :
SELECT distinct n.osm_id, n."addr:housenumber", street.name
FROM planet_osm_line as street
JOIN planet_osm_point as n ON st_dwithin(street.way, n.way, 10)
WHERE street.osm_id = 4227146 AND n."addr:housenumber" is not null
ORDER BY n."addr:housenumber" DESC;

Although, the result is not completely satisfactory since it seems to be missing some house number (i.e. 1, 2, 3...), and that I had to query for every node in a 10meter perimeter.
So, if I understand completely, it appears that we loose some relationship when ingesting the data with osm2pgsql.
